# How do you get a sharpness 32767 sword in Minecraft 1.14.31?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I’m just wondering. Can I get some help please?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade! We’re actually not a normal forum site, so we’re not the place to ask for questions out of the blue. We’re more of a problem solving site once you’ve tried something and are stuck. If you’ve done some research but found nothing, or have made some past trials to no avail, please show us! It’ll make your question more relatable, and better, too!

Comment: @Penguin This would actually be "Needs details or clarity," because an edition is not specified.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 after looking some more it seems that this is Education Edition. It is the only version where 1.14.31 existed

Comment: @Penguin I see, thanks for clarifying. I’m still voting to close though, edition should be explicitly specified by asker. Assuming edition from version number is risky because the number could be misformatted or include typos.